# Can the membership to a private channel in Microsoft Teams be backed by a AAD Group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When creating a ***private channel*** in Microsoft Teams team, do we always have to assign members individually. Can I instead use an ***AAD group*** to back my private channel membership?

I understand that the team itself is backed by an AAD group. And that only the members of the team could actually be assigned to a private channel within that team. If I create an AAD group such that it only has member who are also members of the team, can I use that to back my private channel membership?

Currently I don't find a way to add a group to a private channel or I am overlooking things.

Comment: You can create a team using Group. Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Nikitha. But the question is about creating a private channel backed by a AAD group.

Comment: Currently you can create team from group but there is no API available to create a channel backed by group. Could you please raise a [user Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Answer (score 1):

Copying answer from comments for better understanding.
You can create a team using Group. Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? Currently you can create team from group but there is no API available to create a channel backed by group.